# How to get zeroth-order (piecewise constant) interpolation of scattered data?

Tags: interpolation

Given a collection of scattered data points in 2D and associated function values,

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
```

we can get a piecewise linear interpolating function simply by calling `Interpolation`:

```
interp = Interpolation[data];
Plot3D[interp[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

The result of `Plot3D` is essentially the same as calling `ListPlot3D[data]` directly. I imagine the piecewise linear elements are the Delaunay triangulation of the data points.

However, `ListPlot3D` also allows you to set `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to get a plot that is piecewise *constant* over the Voronoi cells of the data points.

```
ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

I want to get the function corresponding to this plot, but `Interpolation` is of no help here:

> Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.

Is there an easy way to get the result I want, that is, an interpolating function which is piecewise constant on the Voronoi cells of scattered data?

Comment: I'm trying this http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7760/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `Nearest` does it, but I'm having trouble getting a good plot.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 3}];
func = Nearest[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ data];

Plot3D[func[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
 , PlotPoints -> 50
 , ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"
]
```

[image]

For comparison:

```
ListPlot3D[data
 , InterpolationOrder -> 0
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
 , ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh sweet, that was easy! I don't really need a plot, so this is good enough for me.