# How can I define a 3D version of the built-in VoronoiDiagram (VoronoiMesh in V10) function?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, version-10

Can anybody point me in a direction that will guide me to extend the `VoronoiDiagram` function in *Mathematica* to handle 3D (three dimensional) situations (i.e. points in 3D)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

The current `VoronoiMesh` function in **V10** still does not compute 3D Voronoi diagrams, which is strange since both the `DelaunayMesh` and `ConvexHullMesh` functions work with 3D data sets. I guess the waiting continues.... For the Wolfram Research employees, any ideas on why this was omitted, and what is the timeframe for when this functionality will be included in *Mathematica*?

Comment: see `[ComputationalGeometryPackage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/ref/VoronoiDiagram.html)

Comment: @kguler, the VoronoiDiagram function only takes 2D data points and outputs the Voronoi diagram of points in a plane. What I'm trying to create is an equivalent VoronoiDiagram that accepts 3D vectors.

Comment: I think that the v10+ `MeshRegion` does not support arbitrary 3D cells, which would be needed for a representation of a Voronoi tessellation in 3D.  So the mesh region functionality may not help much :-(  One possibility might be using qhull.  It has a command line interface, which can be accessed with RunProcess. MATLAB has qhull built in. If you have MATLAB, you can call it with MATLink.

Answer (score 21):

**Update:** Using  `Raster3D` and  a variation of `func` that returns 4-tuples

```
 data3C = RandomReal[1, {10, 6}]; 
 func3C = Nearest[{#, #2, #3} -> {##4, .03} & @@@ data3C];
 tbl3C = Table[  First[func3C[{x, y, z}]] // Quiet, {x, 0, 1, .01}, 
  {y, 0, 1, .01}, {z, 0, 1, .01}];
```

Examples:

```
 Row[Labeled[Graphics3D[Raster3D[tbl3C, ColorFunction -> #,
  Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}],
 Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 400, 
 SphericalRegion -> True], #, Top] & /@
{Hue, RGBColor, (GrayLevel[#[[1]], .03] &)}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Voronoi images]

```
colorRules = Thread[# -> (ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; Length@#]])] &[
Flatten[tbl3C, 2] // DeleteDuplicates] /.  RGBColor -> List;
Row[Labeled[ Graphics3D[Raster3D[tbl3C /. colorRules, ColorFunction -> #,
  Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True}],
 Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 400, 
 SphericalRegion -> True], #, Top] & /@
{(RGBColor[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], .01] &),
(RGBColor[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], .03] &),
(RGBColor[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], .05] &)}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Voronoi images at various opacities]

---

Using version-9 built-in `Image3D` with @Mr.Wizard's `func`:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 4}]; 
func = Nearest[{#, #2, #3} -> #4 & @@@ data];
dta = Table[func[{x, y, z}] // Quiet, {x, 0, 1, .005}, {y, 0, 1, .005}, {z, 0, 1, .005}];

Grid[Partition[
 Image3D[dta, 
 ImageSize -> 350, ColorFunction -> #, Background -> Black] & /@
 {"SunsetColorsOpacity", "RainbowOpacity", "WhiteBlackOpacity",
  (Append[Blend[{LightBlue, Blue, Yellow}, #], #] &)}, 2]]
```

[image: Wizard's example]

Comment: The free package Voro++ does all the tricks, but it is in C++. This package is used in LAMMPS (Large-scale Atomic/Molecular Massively Parallel Simulator) http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/

Answer (score 16):

Mathematica ships with a [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/) interface called [TetGenLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/guide/TetGenLink.html).  To learn how to use TetGenLink is a bit more work than using the usual Mathematica functions, so I am not going to post a complete solution now.

But the way to go is using TetGenLink.  It can compute a Delaunay tetrahedral mesh, which is the dual of the Voronoi partitioning.  TetGen can also compute Voronoi partitions, but I am not sure if this function is exposed in TetGenLink, you'd have to check.

The function to use is [`TetGenTetrahedralize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/ref/TetGenTetrahedralize.html) and I think you need to read [the TetGen docs](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/switches.html) to understand the second argument (those flags should be the same as the command line options to TetGen).

Comment: Yes, `TetGenLink` is the way to go.

Comment: @ruebenko If you post an answer with the precise command, I'll delete this one.  I'd have to keep reading the docs for a while to figure out the right syntax.

Comment: well `TetGen` will not give you the Voronoi directly. You will need to construct the Voronoi from the tetrahedralization.

Comment: Have you found any undocumented Mathematica feature of the TetGenLink regarding Voronoi partitioning yet? I was not able to find any command which does the trick.

Comment: Or one can use TetGen through `LibraryLink`. However when I have to obtain 3D Voronoi mesh I just write points to a text file `p.node` and run the sytem command `tetgen -v p.node` :)

Answer (score 12):

Note that there's currently no way to represent a collection of 3D Voronoi mesh cells in a `MeshRegion` or `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Here's a routine that takes the dual of the `DelaunayMesh` and returns an `Association` where the keys are the points and the values are their respective Voronoi cells.

```
pad[δ_][{min_, max_}] := {min, max} + δ(max-min){-1, 1}

VoronoiCells[pts_] /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ] && 2 <= Last[Dimensions[pts]] <= 3 := 
  Block[{bds, dm, conn, adj, lc, pc, cpts, hpts, hns, hp, vcells},
    bds = pad[.1] /@ MinMax /@ Transpose[pts];
    dm = DelaunayMesh[pts];

    conn = dm["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, 1]];
    adj = conn . Transpose[conn];

    lc = conn["MatrixColumns"];
    pc = adj["MatrixColumns"];
    cpts = MeshCoordinates[dm];

    vcells = Table[
      hpts = PropertyValue[{dm, {1, lc[[i]]}}, MeshCellCentroid];
      hns = Transpose[Transpose[cpts[[DeleteCases[pc[[i]], i]]]] - cpts[[i]]];
      hp = MapThread[HalfSpace, {hns, hpts}];
      BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, PlotRange -> bds]& /@ hp,
      {i, MeshCellCount[dm, 0]}
    ];

    AssociationThread[cpts, RegionIntersection @@@ vcells]
  ]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[10000];
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];

vc = VoronoiCells[pts]
```

[image]

```
Show[MapIndexed[
  BoundaryMeshRegion[#, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Black, Thick}, 2 -> {ColorData[112][First[#2]]}}] &, 
  Values[vc]
]]
```

[image]

```
Show[
  MapIndexed[
    BoundaryMeshRegion[#, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> {Opacity[0.5], ColorData[112][First[#2]]}}] &, 
    Values[vc]
  ], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}], 
  Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True}
]
```

[image]

Note that this works in 2D too:

```
SeedRandom[10000];
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];

vc = VoronoiCells[pts];

Show[MapIndexed[
  BoundaryMeshRegion[#, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Black, Thick}, 2 -> {ColorData[112][First[#2]]}}] &, 
  Values[vc]
], Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice. I guess one can modify the line computing `bds` so that one can have custom bounds just like in the built-in `VoronoiMesh[]`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another `ContourPlot3D[]`-based method for generating an *approximate* Voronoi diagram. The idea is originally due to [Quílez](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distance/distance.htm).

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["voronoi"]; pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {32, 3}]];
nf = Nearest[pts];

(* gradient-normalized function *)
vfun[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := With[{np = nf[{x, y, z}, 2]},
     (EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, np[[2]]] - EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, np[[1]]])/
     EuclideanDistance[Normalize[{x, y, z} - np[[2]]], Normalize[{x, y, z} - np[[1]]]]]

With[{ε = 1/100}, (* tiny number, increase if you want to see gaps between cells *)
     ContourPlot3D[vfun[x, y, z] == ε, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
                   MaxRecursion -> 1, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 35]]
```

[image: approximate Voronoi diagram]

Answer (score 7):

It would help if you gave an example of a 3D Voronoi diagram.

Perhaps you want something like this, using `Nearest` as I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17076/121).

**Warning:** this is very slow and uses a lot of memory!

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 4}];

func = Nearest[{#, #2, #3} -> #4 & @@@ data];

ContourPlot3D[
 func[{x, y, z}] // Quiet,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> (Hue@#3 &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is that roughly what you want?

Answer (score 7):

[mPower](http://xlr8r.info/mPower/index.html) is what your are looking for, which interfaces with [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/)

I have used this package with *Mathematica* 7 and 8 regularly on both Mac and Windows.
Let's do a testing installation with *Mathematica* 9 on Mac 10.8; you can just delete the folder directly after testing.

[mPower 1.0 for Mathematica 6.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlr8r/files/mQhull%20and%20mPower/mPower-1.0%20for%20Mathematica%206.0/)

[Qhull 12.01 Mac Bindary](http://www.hmug.org/pub/MacOS_X/X/Libraries/Graphics/qhull/)

For the Windows binary, you can grab it directly from [qhull.org](http://qhull.org).

Unzip both packages, create a folder `qhull` under `mpower` folder, then copy `bin` folder from unzipped Qhull package, and put it under the `qhull` folder you just created.

In the mPower folder, open mPower.m in *Mathematica*:

```
$QHULL::usage="$QHULL should contain the name (as a string) of the folder that contains the QHULL binaries on your system.
$QHULL = ToFileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "qhull", "src"}];
```

modify it to

```
$QHULL = ToFileName[{NotebookDirectory[], "qhull", "bin"}];
```

or you can use the absolute path directly

Then, create a new notebook file `test.nb` at the mPower folder

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
<< "mPower.m"
```

You will get two warnings:

```
Warning: regtet binary not found. Expected location: /mPower-1.0-11-May-2008-1631/qhull/bin/

Warning: pwrvtx binary not found. Expected location: /mPower-1.0-11-May-2008-1631/qhull/bin/
```

Ignore them. You are ready to use the qhull interface now.

Run the following code for testing:

```
(* random 3D points *)
points = RandomReal[1, {40, 3}];
(* construct 3D convexhull *)
ch = convexHull[points, convexHullFormat -> {facetNormals -> True, facets -> True}];
(* generate facets for 3D convexhull *)
facetIndices = facets /. ch;
loop[alist_] := Append[alist, alist[[1]]];
loopedFacetIndices = loop /@ facetIndices;
index2xyz[ijklist_] := points[[#]] & /@ ijklist;
loopedFacetCoordinates = index2xyz /@ loopedFacetIndices;
(* visulization 3D convexhull *)
convexObject = 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[points], FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon /@ loopedFacetCoordinates}, 
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

Check the documentation on [boundedCellVoronoi](http://xlr8r.info/mPower/pages/boundedCellVoronoi.html). You can run [the example code](http://xlr8r.info/mPower/pages/examples/boundedCellVoronoi.nb) by copying them into the `test.nb` you just created.

Comment: Looks relevant: http://xlr8r.info/mPower/pages/boundedCellVoronoi.html

Comment: This is quite a bare-bones answer.  Please consider extending it, and adding an example if possible.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's a link to a ready-made package that contains the functionality. The package seems to interface with a mature library, i.e. I expect it to be fast and accurate. I think this is a very useful answer and it leads the way to a solution that is much better than anything with `Nearest`. Lately I have the feeling that on this site we expect too much. Answers which don't give working code are not upvoted even if they give the key to the solution. The OP should really be able to handle it from here. If I were the OP, I'd focus on this answer first and accept as soon as I got it working.

Comment: I took a look at the package, and it seems it's not immediately trivial to set it up with the current version of `qhull`.  So I agree with MrW, if anyone gets it working, please describe how to do it. @Tuku did you get it working?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't discount that we ask a lot on this site, but I disagree that it is *too much*.  Your reversal in the following comment is proof enough of this to me.  Answers *must* be more than a signpost to the information needed to do it yourself, or half the Q's could be answered with a naked link to mathprogramming-intro.org.  It is often *very hard* to determine what is or is not trivial until you attempt it yourself, and those who would vote on such as answer are *negligent in their duty* if they vote without the knowledge from doing so. And that *would* be expecting too much.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was also thinking of answers [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18583/12) where I practically gave the algorithm, but didn't spend the time to implement it.  So it got zero upvotes.  I just didn't want you (or others) to misunderstand this as complaining about the upvotes---I am truly not rep motivated any more.  Also, I do think that this qhull/mPower answer is still too valuable to "hide" it as a comment.  Most likely I could get mPower working again with an hour or two of work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What would you do in the same position, i.e. if you knew about mPower, strongly suspected that it can be fixed up with a little bit of work, but you were not willing to spend the time on it at the moment?  Would you post a comment or an answer with the link but no full solution?  If I'm a googler coming upon this question, I'd much rather see it as an answer than burrowed comment.  Maybe it should be a community wiki answer explaining the situation and encouraging anyone who finishes fixing mPower to edit it and post a full tutorial?  But a *new* SE user wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll have to think about your argument.  For now notice that I did *not* delete this as "not an answer" so my position is not about answer versus comment, but rather *quality* of answer and voting practice.

Comment: @Szabolcs qhull [works](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/#13445) for the Delaunay triangularization using the MathLink program [qh-math](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1160/), but the Voronoi diagram requires one to extract results from qhull differently and that's not implemented in qh-math. (It can calculate the diagram directly; just reading out the data isn't there yet.) Support can probably be added without great difficulty but it doesn't look entirely trivial either.

Comment: @Tuku, thanks for uploading this, but I can't get it to work on Windows. It gives me those two warnings like you said. But uploading your sample code I get the error: Error: convexHull: qconvex failed: no output produced.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work on Windows. For those using Windows like myself, you don't have to change anything as described above. Just copy the files in the "bin" folder from qhull and place them in the "src" folder under the "qhull" folder you created in the UserBaseDirectory.

Answer (score 6):

The extension to 3D is quite non-trivial, and although Wizard's contour plot is impressive, it is an approximation. What you want does not exist in *Mathematica*. I might suggest *Manifold Lab*, which has its own issues but some incredible capabilities as well:

[image: Voronoi model]

Source: ggaliens [link broken, cannot find new one].

Comment: Actually it does exist in Mathematica, see my answer.

Comment: Say, we have a tetrahedralization of the points and the circumcenter to the tets, how does on construct the Voronoi cell of these tetrahedron?

Comment: The Voronoi cells are bounded by the planar polygons formed by the centers of the circumspheres which include a given link in the tetrahedralization.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I am pleased to learn of TetGen!

Comment: @Xerxes, and what do you do at the boundary, where there is no neighboring circumsphere?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, could you explain a bit if there is anything that could be improved such that you would have found this earlier?

Comment: @reubenko:  I don't understand your question; sorry. Let me say this.  Moving from the Delaunay triangulation graph to the Voronoi diagram is a nontrivial computation.  The edges of the DT graph give you bisector planes.  To compute the Voronoi cells, you would have to compute the convex body delimited by these planes.  It is theoretically simple but in practice not easy.  This is why I am so impressed with the ManifoldLab capabilities.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I was trying to ask two things: First, what would have helped you such that you would have found out about the existence of `TetGenLink` earlier that you had and, secondly, if I am not mistaken a Delaunay tetrahedralization is the dual of the Voronoi partitioning. Can you point me to some literature where the transformation from the tetrahedralization to the dual is discussed. I hope this is clearer now. If not let me know.

Comment: @reubenko: The literature on 2D Voronoi diagrams suffices, and is everywhere.  Each Delaunay edge $e$ connects two sites $a$ and $b$. The plane that is the perpendicular bisector of $e$ includes a face of the Voronoi cells of $a$ and $b$. Intersecting the halfspaces for each face of one site yields the convex polyhedral cell for that site.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, thanks; I'll see if I can write an implementation for this. If I succeed I'll post it here.

Comment: @Joseph The link in this post is broken.  If possible would you update it, please?

Answer (score 3):

`VoronoiMesh` was updated in `V 13.1` and now also works in 3D

```
VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 3}],
  MeshCellLabel -> None,
  MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> {Thickness[0.002], Black}, {0, All} -> {PointSize[0.015], Red}}]
```

[image]