# Voronoi diagram for line segments

Tags: computational-geometry

I know that *Mathematica* has built-in functions for creating triangulations and Voronoi diagrams. However, I haven't found a function that would create a Voronoi diagram for line segments. Is there a nice hack for it? Or should I rather write a function myself, or use some C/C++ library like CGAL to import such a function?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/voronoi-diagrams-for-generators-other-than-points)?

Answer (score 14):

This answer took a bit longer to write than I'd like, due to some unexpected complications, which will soon be apparent.

---

In **version 8**, *faking* a Voronoi diagram with `Nearest[]` is easy, because `Nearest[]` has the surprising feature that it supports "unsymmetric" distance functions. For this situation, we need the usual way to compute the point-segment distance:

```
PointSegmentDistance[{x_, y_}, {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
     With[{sv = {x, y} - {x1, y1}, sp = {x2, y2} - {x1, y1}}, 
          EuclideanDistance[sv, Clip[sp.sv/sp.sp, {0, 1}] sp]]
```

Let me proceed with a concrete example. I'll use the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98513) to generate a pile of non-intersecting lines:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1023, Method -> "ExtendedCA"];
            n = 8; k = 1; lines = {RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]};
            While[k < n, test = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}];
                  If[FindIntersections[{Line[lines], Line[test]}] === {},
                     k++; AppendTo[lines, test]]];]
```

Now, generate a `NearestFunction[]`:

```
nf = Nearest[lines, DistanceFunction -> PointSegmentDistance];
```

At this juncture, we can proceed in a manner similar to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115580), using [Schlick's "bias" function](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=brDfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA401):

```
bias[a_, t_] := t/((1/a - 2) (1 - t) + 1)

DensityPlot[bias[0.99, #2 - #1] & @@ (PointSegmentDistance[{x, y}, #] & /@ nf[{x, y}, 2]),
            {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
            PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: line segment Voronoi diagram]

---

In (apparently) **versions 10 and above**, however, `Nearest[]` seems to have been redesigned in a manner that ***no longer supports unsymmetric distance functions***. Thus, the *slower* approach of having to check each line segment is necessary:

```
DensityPlot[bias[0.99, #2 - #1] & @@
            TakeSmallest[PointSegmentDistance[{x, y}, #] & /@ lines, 2],
            {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
            PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: line segment Voronoi diagram]

Comment: Nice work.And I hope the OP have not forgot this question after three years. :)

Answer (score 3):

The method featured in [Okabe *et al.*'s "Spatial Tessellations"](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=dT7YH3mjeeIC&pg=PA287), which I had used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182492), can also be used for this case.

Using the same definition of `lines` in my other answer, we can proceed like so:

```
n = 20; (* number of divisions for shortest line segment *)
divs = Ceiling[n Normalize[EuclideanDistance @@@ lines, Min]];

pp = MapThread[With[{s = Subdivide[0, 1, #2]}, Transpose[{1 - s, s}].#1] &, {lines, divs}];

vm = VoronoiMesh[Flatten[pp, 1]];
facs = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]; cif = Region`Mesh`MeshMemberCellIndex[vm];

DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics[Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[facs[[#]]] & /@
                   Internal`PartitionRagged[cif[Flatten[pp, 1]][[All, -1]], Length /@ pp]]]
```

[image: line segment Voronoi diagram]

Show the diagram along with the generating line segments:

```
Show[%, Graphics[{Red, Line[lines]}]]
```

[image: diagram and lines]