# Hyperbolic Voronoi diagram for the Poincaré model, using RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, regions

I want to compute the Voronoi diagram on the unit disk, using the hyperbolic metric. So, I want to input a list of points and obtain a plot of the cells associated with each of the points.

I defined the metric:

```
 HyperbolicDistance[{a1_, b1_}, {a2_, b2_}] := 
 Module[{d, dist}, 
  d = 2*((EuclideanDistance[{a1, b1}, {a2, 
         b2}]^2)/((1 - EuclideanDistance[{a1, b1}, {0, 0}]^2)*(1 - 
          EuclideanDistance[{a2, b2}, {0, 0}]^2)));
  dist = ArcCosh[1 + d]; Return[dist]]
```

Now, I define the regions, with the list of centers defined by `pts`

```
cells = And @@@ 
   Table[HyperbolicDistance[pts[[i]], {x, y}] <= 
     HyperbolicDistance[pts[[j]], {x, y}], {i, n}, {j, 
     Complement[Range[n], {i}]}];
```

Then, I plot using `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[{cells, x^2 + y^2 < 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> Automatic]
```

I get some warning messages:

`LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 0.844796 +3.14159 I attempted. >>`

which is due to the fact that the metric is defined only on the unit disk and `RegionPlot` is evaluating it on points in the unit square with $-1<x<1,\; -1<y<1$

Is there a way I can evaluate `RegionPlot` in the unit disk, so as to avoid getting this message?

This method is quite inefficient and inaccurate. I can increase the accuracy of the picture by increasing `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, but both are increasing the evaluation time immensely. I am not sure, but I guessed that using the `Nearest` function to evaluate which of the points in the list of Voronoi is closest to a given point $(x,y)$ might improve the code. So I used the `DistanceFunction` to transform the metric used in `Nearest`, but because `RegionPlot` is evaluating it at points where the metric is not valid, so I get the errors like `Nearest::nearuf: The user-supplied distance function HyperbolicDistance does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair {1,1} and {-0.304667,0.852203}. >>`.

Is there a way to improve my code to reduce run time?

I am quite new to *Mathematica*, so any suggestions or insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you have something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lspmW.png) in mind? I use `Nearest[]` for making fake Voronoi diagrams myself. I can post the code for that if you want it.

Comment: @J.M. Those are the kind of pictures I am trying to make. I tried for a while to change the metric in VoronoiDiagram, but I didn't see a way of doing that, and that's why I am trying this low-tech method.

Comment: Nah, `VoronoiDiagram[]` does not currently support other metrics at the moment. So you wouldn't mind my posting a fake?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, please!

Comment: Although it's a pain, it will greatly improve your performance to generate polygons for each reason and use `Polygon` instead of `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**

(incorporating comments by J. M.: `DistanceFunction -> dis` and pre-computation of nearest function):

This is not efficient. Just rewriting metric (apologies for errors). In the following I used `ContourPlot` but `DensityPlot` could be used.

```
dis[a_, b_] := Abs[ArcCosh[1 + 2 ( a - b).(a - b)/((1 - a.a) (1 - b.b))]]
vh[n_] := Module[{p = RandomPoint[Disk[], n], nf},
nf = Nearest[p, DistanceFunction -> dis];
ContourPlot[First[nf[{x, y}]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{u, v}, u^2 + v^2 <= 1], 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

`vh` visualizes using `Nearest` with `dis` as distance function.

Some examples: `Range[5, 45, 5]` (takes quite some time):

[image: hyperbolic Voronoi]

Apologies for errors (typographical and conceptual). I look forward to much better answers.

Comment: `DistanceFunction -> dis` suffices, of course. :) As for "takes quite some time", you can store `Nearest[p, DistanceFunction -> dis]` so that `ContourPlot[]` does not have to recompute so many times.

Comment: Thanks! This looks nice! But, why are some boundaries not computing? When I run your code, and in some pictures above, there are some regions with two or more points. Do I insert Nearest[p,DistanceFunction->dis] into Module?

Comment: @user1974 thanks. DensityPlot and changing numeric a aspects (plot points, max recursion etc) may improve quality. ColorFunction may help discrimination of regions. I am sure others will have better ways or you can play around. It is late in my Timezone, I have had 2 drinks and am off to sleep. Best wishes and good luck:)

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, as always... You are absolutely right...I had written a DynamicModule with LocatorPane that required calculation of a new NearestFunction but it was too slow...I just copied and pasted old code (in dim witted way). Will correct when time permits. Thanks again.:)

Answer (score 9):

Here is some code I have for making **fake** Voronoi diagrams, adapted to the Poincaré disk model. The result has the look and feel of having been drawn with a charcoal pencil, which may or may not be desired for your application. The strategy is adapted from suggestions by [Worley](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/237170.237267) and [Schlick](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=brDfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA401).

```
(* some points *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; 
            pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 35]];

poincareMetric[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] := 
               Abs[ArcCosh[1 + 2 SquaredEuclideanDistance[u, v]/((1 - u.u) (1 - v.v))]]

(* Schlick's "bias" function, following Perlin and Hoffert *)
bias[a_, t_] := t/((1/a - 2) (1 - t) + 1)

With[{nodeFun = Nearest[pts, DistanceFunction -> poincareMetric]},
     Quiet @ DensityPlot[bias[0.99, HarmonicMean[#] - First[#]] & @
                         Map[poincareMetric[{x, y}, #] &, Take[nodeFun[{x, y}, 2], 2]],
                         {x, y} ∈ Disk[], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                         ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, 
                         PlotPoints -> 150, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: fake Voronoi diagram for the Poincaré metric]

The first argument of the `bias[]` function can be adjusted as seen fit. The following image is the result of setting the first parameter to `0.9`:

[image: slightly darkened]

where the dots corresponding to the original point positions become more pronounced, at the expense of darkening the shading within the cells.

---

For completeness, here is the result of using the Beltrami-Klein metric instead:

```
beltramiMetric[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] :=
        Abs[ArcCosh[(1 - u.v)/Sqrt[(1 - u.u) (1 - v.v)]]]

With[{nodeFun = Nearest[pts, DistanceFunction -> beltramiMetric]},
     Quiet @ DensityPlot[bias[0.99, HarmonicMean[#] - First[#]] & @
                         Map[beltramiMetric[{x, y}, #] &, Take[nodeFun[{x, y}, 2], 2]],
                         {x, y} ∈ Disk[], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                         ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, 
                         PlotPoints -> 150, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: fake Voronoi diagram for the Beltrami metric]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach for generating *fake* Voronoi diagrams. This also uses `Nearest[]` with the Poincaré disk metric, but uses [Quílez](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distance/distance.htm)'s gradient normalization (similar to the approach used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133712)).

With the same definition for `pts` and `poincareMetric[]` as in my other answer:

```
poincareGradient[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] := 
        4 Sinh[poincareMetric[u, v]/2]^2 (u/(1 - Norm[u]^2) +
        (u - v)/SquaredEuclideanDistance[u, v])/Sinh[poincareMetric[u, v]]

smoothStep = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x, _Real}}, 
                     Module[{t = Min[Max[0, (x - a)/(b - a)], 1]}, 
                            t t t ((6 t - 15) t + 10)], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

DensityPlot[With[{dm = Take[nf[{x, y}, 2], 2]}, 
                 smoothStep[0.01, 0.005, (poincareMetric[{x, y}, dm[[2]]] -
                                          poincareMetric[{x, y}, dm[[1]]])/
                                         Norm[poincareGradient[{x, y}, dm[[2]]] - 
                                              poincareGradient[{x, y}, dm[[1]]]]]],
            {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1 - Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
            ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}],
            Epilog -> {Thick, Circle[]}, PlotPoints -> 75, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fake Voronoi diagram on Poincaré disk]

---

A similar technique can also be used to fake Voronoi diagrams on the Poincaré *ball* (with a quarter of the ball cut away to reveal internal structure):

[image: fake Voronoi diagram on Poincaré ball]

---

This approach is of course still usable if you want to use the Beltrami-Klein metric instead; one only needs to derive the gradient expression for the Beltrami-Klein metric and then you can proceed analogously.

Comment: Very pretty on the ball !