# Areas of Voronoi cells from an image file

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry, distributions

I have a binary image with non-point objects.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to determine area of each Voronoi cell in Voronoi diagram (the goal is area distribution)?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate a Voronoi diagram for non-point objects?

Comment: Related: [(20696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/voronoi-diagrams-for-generators-other-than-points)

Comment: They started and finished with images. I found difficult for me to derive numerical areas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a one-liner (if you have wide enough screen)

```
Histogram@ComponentMeasurements[#, "Area"][[;; , 2]] &@
   WatershedComponents@DistanceTransform@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0EUJ.png"
```

[image]

Comment: Now, that's terseness :D

Comment: It's a One Line Mathematica Lesson®.