# How to obtain the adjacency matrix of morphological components?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, segmentation

I am wondering if there's a simple way to obtain the adjacency matrix of the morphological components of a segmented image. Consider the following example (originally, from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/voronoi-diagrams-for-generators-other-than-points)):

```
(*Import binary image*)
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/iab6u.png"];

(*Obtain the distance transform*)
disT = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[image]];

(*Visualize the watershed morphological components*)
wComp = WatershedComponents[disT];
morphoComp = MorphologicalComponents[wComp];
imgMorphoC = Dilation[morphoComp // Colorize, 1];
ImageMultiply[imgMorphoC, ColorNegate[image]]
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to obtain the adjacency matrix of the resulting components? I suspect there's a way to transform `morphoComp` into an adjacency matrix, or a graph/network, but I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: I tried to simply do `ComponentMeasurements[image, "Neighbors"]`, but it retrieves an empty list of neighbors. From the documentation it is unclear what is meant by `"Neighbors"`, are these only touching components?

**Edit 1.1**: Doing `ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[morphoComp, 1], "Neighbors"]` works:

```
{1 -> {3, 4, 5, 7}, 2 -> {5, 6}, 3 -> {1, 7, 8}, 4 -> {1, 5, 6, 7, 8},
  5 -> {1, 2, 4, 6}, 6 -> {2, 4, 5, 8, 9}, 7 -> {1, 3, 4, 8}, 
 8 -> {3, 4, 6, 7}, 9 -> {6}}
```

**Edit 2**: Could this be done so that only neighbors up to a certain distance are considered adjacent? Say, that from the original morphological components, they are grown n number of pixels around their border (with `Dilation[]`, for instance), and only these components coming in contact after this dilation would be considered neighbors.

Comment: See the documentation of `ComponentMeasurements` -> Application section -> last  example. That might help.

Comment: Just to put it here: the reason you're getting an empty list of neighbors with `ComponentMeasurements` is because of the `0`'s separating each component in `morphoComp`. Use `MaxFilter[morphoComp, 1]` and it should work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by asking for it do be done such that only neighbors up to a certain distance are considered adjacent? Aren't all neighbors already 0 distance apart? Do you mean that even neighbors that might be not touching, but below a certain distance apart, ought to be considered adjacent?

Comment: @thorimur Oh, you're right. I'll reformulate this part. I'm thinking of a given component, if "grown" n pixels around its borders (dilation), it considers a neighbor whatever other component(s) it got in touch with. This sort of distance I'm thinking about. I don't think it is a "watershed distance", maybe there's a better term? Would this need to be done simultaneously for all components? P.S. Yeah, using MaxFilter[morphoComp, 1] seems to work, thanks!

Comment: So `a = ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[morphoComp, 1], "Neighbors"];
SparseArray[Join @@ (Thread@*List @@@ a) -> 1]` would construct the adjacency matrix, right?

Comment: For edit 2: could you use `DistanceMatrix[
 ComponentMeasurements[MaxFilter[morphoComp, 1], "Centroid"][[All, 
   2]]]` ? to select by criteria? little clunky though