# Manipulating Images

Tags: image-processing

I would like to get information from an Imagen. Specifically, I have this image of cells in a tissue (you can identify a cell because it is border by a lighter purple).

[image]

What kind of Mathematica's functions can help to extract the network of connections between cells?

Comment: thresholding the image, taking the `MorphologicalComponents`, and maybe doing something in the spirit of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236466/how-to-obtain-the-adjacency-matrix-of-morphological-components) (which doesn't have an answer, but some leads in the comments) might be an approach...

Comment: There are several examples of processing cell images [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/image-computation-for-microscopy/segmentation-and-classification-of-cells.html?product=mathematica).

Comment: Similar examples [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201974/segmenting-cells-from-a-stained-image-of-cells-from-microscope) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128596/how-to-get-cell-boundaries-in-the-image/128609)