# VoronoiMesh for 3D points

Tags: geometry, version-10

I believe that this is a doc error in V10 (this was programmed to be but not implemented). The new [`VoronoiMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html) should work for 3D set of points.

The [`DelaunayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) function works. Here is a doc example:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 3}];
DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 3}]]
```

[image]

But if you try:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 3}];
VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

You get the error:
[image]

Docs for Voronoi say:

> The cells will be intervals in 1D, convex polygons in 2D, and convex
>   polyhedra in 3D.

Tested in V10.0.0 for Mac and Win.

Comment: I have already talked about this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18893/how-can-i-define-a-3d-version-of-the-built-in-voronoidiagram-voronoimesh-in-v10). I'm not so sure it is a bug, rather it has not been implemented but planned. Because internally the new `Mesh` functions rely on `TetGen` which supports 3D voronoi diagrams but somehow this functionality has been omitted.

Comment: @Szabolcs no! Typo.

Comment: Not implemented in V10.0.1 yet

Comment: I didn't expect it to be implemented. When I asked about it in one of the online seminars they had, their response made me believe it will come in **V11** or later.

Comment: ... and it hasn't come as of v12.2.