# Perturb lattice positions for non-overlapping particles

Tags: graphics3d, lattices

Using the below commands, a simple lattice configuration can be generated:

```
Cube = Normal@LatticeData["SimpleCubic", "Basis"];
LatPos = Flatten[Table[i Cube[[1]] + j Cube[[2]] + k Cube[[3]], {i, 0, 100, 
 5}, {j, 0, 100, 5}, {k, 0, 10, 5}], 2];
Graphics3D[Map[Sphere[#, parsize] &, #], Boxed -> True, Axes -> True] & /@ {LatPos}
```

for particle size (parsize) equals to one, one can have:
[image]

At the next step, I need to move these particles in the random directions (starting with small movement) in the condition that particles do not overlap. 
I used the below code to generate the movements and check if they have intersections or not. However, it took forever to run when the number of particles is large.

```
maxRanNum = 0.5;
LatPos2 = {}; Do[Label[ran]; r = RandomReal[{-maxRanNum, maxRanNum}, 3];If[0 <= r[[1]] + LatPos[[i]][[1]] <= 100 && 0 <= r[[2]] + LatPos[[i]][[2]] <= 100 && 0 <= r[[3]] + LatPos[[i]][[3]] <= 10,LatPos2 = AppendTo[LatPos2, LatPos[[i]] + r],Goto[ran]], {i, Length[LatPos]}];
Graphics3D[Map[Sphere[#, parsize] &, #], Boxed -> True, Axes -> True] & /@ {LatPos2}
```

[image]

and to check the itersections:

```
Do[If[i == j, Continue[]]; intersection = RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[Sphere[LatPos2[[i]], parsize],Sphere[LatPos2[[j]], parsize]]];
If[intersection != 0, Print[false];
Break[], Continue[]], {i, Length[LatPos2]}, {j, Length[LatPos2]}]
```

so I suppose that creating the movement of the lattice particles need to be coded together with the overlapping check. But I do not know how it can be done. 
I appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: @kglr 
 Since I used your good suggestion before, regarding the same problem, I supposed maybe you can help me in this regard too. Thank you.

Comment: Bahar, this is much tougher than your previous question:) I will post an answer if I come up with something. It looks like you need to generate a [RandomPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) in each of  the 3D VoronoiMesh cells. But, unfortunately, `VoronoiMesh` works only for 1D and 2D.  [This q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18893/125) may be useful. See also  [TriangulateMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangulateMesh.html?q=TriangulateMesh) and [Insphere](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Insphere.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at them.

Answer (score 3):

This should be much more efficient for counting the number of sphere intersections:

```
intersections[LatPos_] := 
 Total[
   Length /@ Nearest[LatPos -> Automatic, LatPos, {∞, 2 parsize}] 
  ] - Length[LatPos]
```

We use that two spheres intersect if and only if the distance of the center points is less or equal to the sum of radii. Moreover, we use `Nearest` to find for each point in `LatPos` the list of the indices of all points (this is why `∞` appears) that have distance less or equal to `2 parsize`. Afterwards, we count the total number of indices and subtract `Length[LatPos]` since every point has distance `0` to itself.

**Edit**

Should it be impossible to feed `Nearest` with a second argument which is a list of points, you can also use the following function (with a certain loss of performance)

```
intersections2[LatPos_] := With[{nf = Nearest[LatPos -> Automatic]},
  Total[Length[nf[#, {∞, 2 parsize}]] & /@ LatPos] - Length[LatPos]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand your explanations, but it gives me the following error when I run the code:

Comment: In[140]:= intersections[LatPos]


During evaluation of In[140]:= Nearest::dmtch:
 The dimension of {{0.,0.,0.},{0.,74.822,0.},{74.822,0.,0.},{74.822,74.822,0.}}->Automatic and {{0.,0.,0.},{0.,74.822,0.},{74.822,0.,0.},{74.822,74.822,0.}} does not match. >>

During evaluation of In[140]:= Nearest::near1: 
2 is neither a list of real points nor a valid list of rules. >>


Out[140]= 4

Comment: You have to give a numerical value to `parsize`.

Comment: Yes, I did. parsize=1.

Comment: If it still won't work, try to remove `-> Automatic`. Which version of Mathematica do you use?

Comment: I found that what is the error about. It is not about "Automatic". The error can be solved when I substitute the second "LatPos" in the "Nearest" function with a single position property, such as "{0,0,0}'.

Comment: Do I need to use a "Do" loop to check for each "LatPos" elements?

Comment: Okay. It does work in version 11.0.1, though. I also posted a `Do`-less workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I think the new version is able to run your code. So I am trying to get the new version as well. Since I saw some other bugs in the version (Mathematica 10)  I already have.

Comment: I got the new version and it is working perfectly. It is so fast. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!