# Draw partition of 3D polygon

Tags: graphics3d, partitions, polyhedra

I want to draw a partition of an arbitrary 3D polyhedron like this drawing.

Where can I find examples of how to draw this?

[image]

**Upd:**

For example, I have this code on python

```
m = 45
partition = [[23, 24, 2, 25, 26, 27, 7, 28, 29, 3, 30, 31, 14, 32, 33, 1, 0], [24, 17, 25, 23, 34, 35, 36, 22, 30, 37, 19, 31, 38, 18, 39], [4, 35, 40, 24, 34, 20, 11, 41, 30, 37, 28, 42, 33, 32, 13, 12, 21], [24, 35, 26, 16, 15, 36, 8, 41, 5, 40, 27, 6, 9, 39, 43, 38, 44, 23, 29, 10, 28, 42]]
points = [[-0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746, 0.5], [-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373], [-0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373], [-0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746, 0.5], [0.5, -0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746], [0.5, 0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746], [0.20710678118654746, 0.5, 0.20710678118654746], [-0.20710678118654746, 0.5, 0.20710678118654746], [0.5, 0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746], [0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373], [0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746, 0.5], [0.5, -0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746], [0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746, 0.5], [0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373], [-0.7071067811865475, 0.0, 0.0], [0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373], [0.20710678118654746, 0.5, -0.20710678118654746], [-0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373], [-0.20710678118654746, 0.5, -0.20710678118654746], [-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373], [0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373], [0.0, -0.7071067811865475, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -0.7071067811865475], [-0.2824105505829383, 0.4247008996483171, -0.13705193185085648], [-0.02048188208948376, -0.01571424304076291, -0.01743874711809676], [-0.49806108666697857, 0.20904227237865944, -0.209045063679455], [-0.20710804045379536, 0.5000004446965807, 0.16190362960014762], [-0.1860300020235808, 0.49999812977709335, 0.2071089405020803], [0.12268057204041909, -0.005082997932443401, 0.499996491348166], [-0.00931983295438987, 0.2071071079673102, 0.4999977236555634], [-0.3206566352385273, -0.38644733328441644, -0.15677218363806888], [-0.48159060502762374, -0.2255153297585916, -0.22551726849858902], [0.00032108123217798964, -0.2071067019060003, 0.5000019952637891], [-0.24363815128018354, -0.46346242144613514, 0.2436419734397271], [0.3013193865154568, -0.30133316310518343, -0.4057777203267997], [0.3384181722613934, 0.00866654027637278, -0.3686918868729873], [0.30881336789975355, 0.3088202082474216, -0.3982891162766628], [-0.2403681923428138, -0.46673647792715633, -0.24037111350962848], [-0.1927414165848333, 0.4999975805569351, -0.20711009551652088], [-0.20710856459360286, 0.5000017834070557, -0.16321725869229695], [0.49999879511484707, -0.04251680401656357, -0.20710645976695208], [0.4999960380431533, -0.03236895298986859, 0.207107581402605], [0.2071109676453297, -0.14497532187633846, 0.4999992902408488], [-0.03380956932061133, 0.4548601941166912, -0.25224658706985625], [-0.03392324018536094, 0.018480809098675582, -0.026412841964440804]]
```

Here, the `partition` stores indexes from `points` of the corresponding polyhedra of the partition. I want to draw them preferably in different colors and preferably with a little transparency. How can I do this? (`m = 45` number of points of the split polyhedron)

Comment: Note, image is taken from [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18893/13)  where there is already good starting code.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

The updated question maybe

```
Clear[partition, points];
partition = {{23, 24, 2, 25, 26, 27, 7, 28, 29, 3, 30, 31, 14, 32, 33,
     1, 0}, {24, 17, 25, 23, 34, 35, 36, 22, 30, 37, 19, 31, 38, 18, 
    39}, {4, 35, 40, 24, 34, 20, 11, 41, 30, 37, 28, 42, 33, 32, 13, 
    12, 21}, {24, 35, 26, 16, 15, 36, 8, 41, 5, 40, 27, 6, 9, 39, 43, 
    38, 44, 23, 29, 10, 28, 42}};
partition = partition + 1;
points = {{-0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5}, {-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373}, {-0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373}, {-0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5}, {0.5, -0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746}, {0.5, 
    0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746}, {0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5, 0.20710678118654746}, {-0.20710678118654746, 0.5, 
    0.20710678118654746}, {0.5, 0.20710678118654746, 
    0.20710678118654746}, {0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373}, {0.20710678118654746, 0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5}, {0.5, -0.20710678118654746, 
    0.20710678118654746}, {0.20710678118654746, -0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5}, {0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373}, {-0.7071067811865475, 0.0, 
    0.0}, {0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373}, {0.20710678118654746, 
    0.5, -0.20710678118654746}, {-0.35355339059327373, 
    0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373}, {-0.20710678118654746,
     0.5, -0.20710678118654746}, {-0.35355339059327373, \
-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373}, {0.35355339059327373, \
-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373}, {0.0, \
-0.7071067811865475, 0.0}, {0.0, 
    0.0, -0.7071067811865475}, {-0.2824105505829383, 
    0.4247008996483171, -0.13705193185085648}, {-0.02048188208948376, \
-0.01571424304076291, -0.01743874711809676}, {-0.49806108666697857, 
    0.20904227237865944, -0.209045063679455}, {-0.20710804045379536, 
    0.5000004446965807, 0.16190362960014762}, {-0.1860300020235808, 
    0.49999812977709335, 
    0.2071089405020803}, {0.12268057204041909, -0.005082997932443401, 
    0.499996491348166}, {-0.00931983295438987, 0.2071071079673102, 
    0.4999977236555634}, {-0.3206566352385273, -0.38644733328441644, \
-0.15677218363806888}, {-0.48159060502762374, -0.2255153297585916, \
-0.22551726849858902}, {0.00032108123217798964, -0.2071067019060003, 
    0.5000019952637891}, {-0.24363815128018354, -0.46346242144613514, 
    0.2436419734397271}, {0.3013193865154568, -0.30133316310518343, \
-0.4057777203267997}, {0.3384181722613934, 
    0.00866654027637278, -0.3686918868729873}, {0.30881336789975355, 
    0.3088202082474216, -0.3982891162766628}, {-0.2403681923428138, \
-0.46673647792715633, -0.24037111350962848}, {-0.1927414165848333, 
    0.4999975805569351, -0.20711009551652088}, {-0.20710856459360286, 
    0.5000017834070557, -0.16321725869229695}, {0.49999879511484707, \
-0.04251680401656357, -0.20710645976695208}, {0.4999960380431533, \
-0.03236895298986859, 
    0.207107581402605}, {0.2071109676453297, -0.14497532187633846, 
    0.4999992902408488}, {-0.03380956932061133, 
    0.4548601941166912, -0.25224658706985625}, {-0.03392324018536094, 
    0.018480809098675582, -0.026412841964440804}};
HighlightMesh[
    ConvexHullMesh[points[[#]]], {Style[1, None], 
     Style[2, Opacity[.5], RandomColor[]]}] & /@ partition // Show
```

[image]

**Original**

Not so effective.Voronoi mesh.

```
Clear[pts, regs];
pts = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1, 2/3}, {1, 1, 1/10}, {1/3, 1/2, 
    1}};
regs = And @@@ 
   Table[EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], {x, y, z}] <= 
     EuclideanDistance[pts[[j]], {x, y, z}], {i, Length[pts]}, {j, 
     Complement[Range[Length[pts]], {i}]}];
Show[RegionPlot3D[regs, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {2.43, 1.76, 2.23}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You are making a Voronoi diagram, and I want to draw a specific partition of a specific polyhedron.