# Interpolation of data on a 4D grid

Tags: interpolation, tetgenlink

I have a 4D grid

```
l=50; Ω = Table[{(i1 - 9/10)/(2*l), (i2 - 9/10)/(2*l), (i3 - 9/10)/(2*l), (i4 - 9/10)/(2*l), 
 1 - (i1 - 9/10)/(2*l) - (i2 - 9/10)/(2*l) - (i3 - 9/10)/(2*l) - (i4 - 9/10)/(2*l)}, {i1, 1,  2l}, {i2, 1, 2l - i1 + 1}, {i3, 1, 2l - (i1 + i2)+2}, {i4, 1, 2l - (i1 + i2 + i3)+3}];
```

and I need to find an interpolating function over this grid. If I use the standard `Interpolation` function, I get "unstructured grid" error. To work around this problem, I've been using the following code (which I found at [Interpolation on a regular square grid spanning a triangular domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77786/interpolation-on-a-regular-square-grid-spanning-a-triangular-domain)) for a 3D grid

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; Needs["TetGenLink`"]; tmpF2T={}; l=50; Ω = Flatten[ Table[{(i1 - 9/10)/(2*l), (i2 - 9/10)/(2*l), (i3 - 9/10)/(2*l),  1 - (i1 - 9/10)/(2*l) - (i2 - 9/10)/(2*l) - (i3 -    9/10)/(2*l)}, {i1, 1, 2l}, {i2, 1, 2l - i1 + 1}, {i3, 1, 2l - (i1 + i2)+2}], 0]; ΩSubset =  DelaunayMesh[Flatten[Ω[[All, All, All, {1, 2, 3}]], 2]]; emesh =  ToElementMesh[ "Coordinates" -> MeshCoordinates[ΩSubset],   "MeshElements" -> {TetrahedronElement@
 Pick[First@
   Thread[MeshCells[ΩSubset, 3], Tetrahedron], 
  Unitize[Chop@
    Flatten@PropertyValue[{ΩSubset, 3}, 
      MeshCellMeasure]], 1]}]; AppendTo[tmpF2T,ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, loc[[All, 1]]]];
```

where loc[[All, 1]] is a list of function values defined over the `Ω` grid. These function values are largely irrelevant for this question, and can be replaced with, say, `Table[50, {i,1,Length[ΩSubset]}]`. The code has been working great for 3D. It removes the problematic points that cause issues in interpolation, and then interpolation works just fine.

Now I need to do the same thing for my four dimensional grid. But, DelaunayMesh does not seem to be producing a grid in this case. So my question is, what is the right way to extend this code to four and possibly five dimensions? And should I be using "Tetrahedron" and "TetrahedronElement" for more than 3 dimensions?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code in copyable format.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to put it in "code" format.

Comment: Majid, what are you trying to achieve by `Flatten[..., 0]` in your definitions of Omega? That level specification is equivalent to no flattening at all.

Comment: Yes, i know, it's just that sometimes i need to flatten the grid, so I leave it inside Flatten.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should remove it here, though. It is confusing and it reduces the legibility of your code. More in general, I wonder if you could reduce your problem to a smaller, more manageable size (i.e. a *minimal working example*). That will be more likely to attract attention and generate good answers.

Comment: In the first code `i2min` is not defined, so the Iterator `{i1,1,101-i2min}` fails. In the second code section there are syntax problems. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I don't think the built-in meshers can go beyond 3D, though the documentation is vague on limitations.  Maybe someone will correct me.  Example: "DiscretizeRegion::cdim: The region given at position 1 in DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1}]] is in dimension 4. DiscretizeRegion only supports dimensions 1 through 3."  One can get a 4D `{x, y, z}` x `{t}` interpolation; see "Transient PDEs" in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your data is not on a simple grid. Let's simplify a bit and we'll see that Interpolation can handle 4-dimensional data.

```
l = 5;
f[i1_, i2_, i3_, i4_] := i1 + i2 + i3 + i4; 
omega = Table[{{i1, i2, i3, i4}, f[i1, i2, i3, i4]}, 
              {i1, l}, {i2, l}, {i3, l}, {i4, l}];
```

Now if you look at omega, you'll see that the parentheses are all wrong for the form needed to input into Interpolation. This can be fixed by judicious flattening:

```
g = Interpolation[Flatten[omega, 3]]
```

Hence, for example,

```
g[2, 2.1, 2.2, 1.5]

7.8
```

Comment: But the main issue I am facing with the standard Interpolation function is that it returns me "Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid." error, when I define omega as: `omega = Table[{{i1, i2, i3, i4}, f[i1, i2, i3, i4]}, 
              {i1, l}, {i2, l-(i1)+1}, {i3, l-(i1+i2)+2}, {i4, l-(i1+i2+i3)+3}]; g = Interpolation[Flatten[omega, 3]];` This is why I am using that bit of code shown in my question.