# Interpolation of non-rectangular data failed

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, interpolation

I want to interpolate a type of data which is on a triangular lattice in order to make DensityPlot faster(ListDensityPlot is so slow). However, the interoplation failed with error, no matter setting `InterpolationOrder->1` or `InterpolationOrder->All`

Here is a less dense data

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/6XmFDzmf"];
plotData = 
  Partition[
   StringCases[data, x : NumberString :> Internal`StringToDouble@x], 
   3];
Interpolation[plotData]
```

it will raise several errors

> Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently
>   only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All.
>   Order will be reduced to 1.
>
> Interpolation::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of
>   0.`. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.
>
> Interpolation::fememtlq: The quality 0.`of the underlying mesh is too
>   low. The quality needs to be larger than 0.`.

What does it mean? How to interpolate such data or general non-rectangular data?

PS: the density plot is

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that for regular (but not rectangular) meshes the Delaunay mesh is unstable. It's a bug, also mentioned [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77786/interpolation-on-a-regular-square-grid-spanning-a-triangular-domain), which was about rectangular grids. The same workaround works here -- just jiggle the points a tiny bit around their perfect lattice positions:

```
epsilon = 10^-7;
jiggledPlotData = {#1 + RandomReal[epsilon {-1, 1}], #2 + 
      RandomReal[epsilon {-1, 1}], #3} & @@@ plotData;
reg = ConvexHullMesh[jiggledPlotData[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
f = Interpolation[jiggledPlotData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

A better method than jiggle original grid which I learned recently is dealing with mesh explicitly.

First, we need a package

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
```

We can generate Delaunay mesh by

```
originalMesh = ToElementMesh[plotData[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]]
```

but this will throw a warning message

> ToElementMesh::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of
> 0.`. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.

this is the same femimq problem, though the mesh looks fine at first sight as(enlarged)

[image]

The ElementMesh provides powerful tools to examing what is going on.

```
originalMesh["Quality"][[1]] // Histogram
```

[image]

The histogram shows most of the triangle has good quality close to 1. But there are plenty of triangle has quality near 0 which are bad enough.

using `highlightBadMeshElement`(code at the end), we can show the location of these bad triangles.

```
highlightBadMeshElement[originalMesh, 0.2]
```

[image]

They are all located at the edge shown by red marker.

We can delete these redundent bad triangles and form a refined mesh using `refineMesh`(code at the end)

```
mesh = refineMesh[originalMesh, 0.2];
f = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, plotData[[;; , -1]]];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

gives

[image]

---

functions:

```
highlightBadMeshElement[mesh_, qualityThreshold_] := Module[{},
  pos = Position[mesh["Quality"], _?(# <= qualityThreshold &)];
  Show[
   mesh["Wireframe"[
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.6]], FaceForm[]]]],
   mesh["Wireframe"[pos, "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]
   , Boxed -> False]]

refineMesh[mesh_, qualityThreshold_] := Module[{},
   qualityList = First@mesh["Quality"];
   pos = Flatten@Position[qualityList, _?(# > qualityThreshold &)];
   If[Length@mesh["MeshElements"] != 1,
    Message[refineMesh::MoreThanOneTypeOfElement,
     Head /@ mesh["MeshElements"]];Abort[],
    elementHead = Head@First@mesh["MeshElements"];
    ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"], 
     "MeshElements" -> {elementHead[
        mesh["MeshElements"][[1, 1, pos]]]}]]];
refineMesh::MoreThanOneTypeOfElement = 
  "More than one type of element. `1`";
```